# Can not remove last array json in with command line mongodb with $pull?

Tags: mongodb

I want to delete the last array of Array "status.data" using the mongodb $ pull But I do not know why I can not delete it please help. Any suggestion please

my collection

```
let data=[{
"_id" : "001-00002246",
"branchId" : "001", 
"status" : {
    "title" : "closed",
    "data" : [
        {
            "createdDate" : ISODate("2017-10-13T16:36:56.676+07:00"),
            "status" : "active",
            "memo" : "init"
        },
        {
            "createdDate" : ISODate("2018-03-31T13:35:57.708+07:00"),
            "status" : "dropout",
            "memo" : "ប្ដូរទៅលំនៅ"
        },
        {
            "createdDate" : ISODate("2018-06-07T10:57:42.967+07:00"),
            "status" : "closed",
            "memo" : "close the section"
        }
    ]
 }
}]
```

my script do not work for remove last array

```
let data = db.school_sectionDetail.find({ sectionId: '001-000079', 
 'status.title': 'closed' })
  data.forEach((it) => {
let arrSort = it.status.data.sort((a, b) => a.createdDate - 
                         b.createdDate)
let checkAfterLast = arrSort[arrSort.length - 2]

if (checkAfterLast != 'active') {
    db.school_sectionDetail.update({ sectionId: it.sectionId },
        {
            $set: { 'status.title': checkAfterLast.status },
            $pull: { 'status.data': { 'status.title': 'closed' } }
        }, { multi: true })
}
});
```

I want result like that

```
let data=[{
"_id" : "001-00002246",
"branchId" : "001", 
"status" : {
    "title" : "drop",
    "data" : [
        {
            "createdDate" : ISODate("2017-10-13T16:36:56.676+07:00"),
            "status" : "active",
            "memo" : "init"
        },
        {
            "createdDate" : ISODate("2018-03-31T13:35:57.708+07:00"),
            "status" : "dropout",
            "memo" : "ប្ដូរទៅលំនៅ"
        },          
    ]
 }
}]
```

Comment: What is `let checkAfterLast = arrSort[arrSort.length - 2]` doing ? Also it returns array element. You have to use checkAfterLast.status in the next line for comparing status and pull should be `$pull: { 'status.data': { 'status': 'closed' } }`

Comment: Ok I see thank you